# longest path in a tree starting from 0 in java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a tree having N nodes and N-1 links connecting them.

Nodes are labeled with distinct numbers in range [0 to N-1]

Links connect nodes in such a way that each pair of distinct nodes is connected by a direct link or along a path consisting of direct links.

There is a exactly one way to reach any node from any other node.

Now for my task starting node is 0. I want to visit as many nodes as possible.
I do not want to visit any node more than once and I can only move along direct links.
As per my task I may end at any node, I just wanted to find longest path possible.

But I have a constraint here, I can visit at most one odd numbered nodes (1,3,5, etc) in my logic.

The input for my program is represented as an array 'A' such that:

```
A[0] = 0;
A[P] = Q and P!= 0, then there is a direct link between nodes P & Q.
```

**Example with 10 nodes and 9 links:**

```
Lets say A={0,9,0,2,6,8,0,8,3,0};


4--6--0--2--3--8--5
      |        |
      9        7
      |
      1(one)


This example should return 4, as there is a longest path 0->2->3->8. Node 3 is the only odd numbered node here.
```

**Example 2:**

```
A = [0,0,0,1,6,1,0,0]

          7 
          |     
    5--1--0--6--4   
       |  |
       3  2 

This example should return 3, as there is a path longest 0->6->4.
```

I have come up with below code to solve this program:

```
public static int longestPath(int[] T) {
        List<Integer>[] nodes = new ArrayList[T.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
            if (T[i] != i) {
                nodes[i].add(T[i]);
                nodes[T[i]].add(i);
            }
        }
        List<Integer> connectedNodes = nodes[0];

        int longestPath = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < connectedNodes.size(); i++) {
            int nextNode = connectedNodes.get(i);
            int count = 1;
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(0);
            set.add(nextNode);
            int odds = 0;
            if (nextNode % 2 != 0) {
                odds++;
            }
            count++;
            while (true) {
                List<Integer> arrayList = nodes[nextNode];
                arrayList.sort(null);
                int next = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
                if (!set.contains(next)) {
                    set.add(next);
                    if (next % 2 != 0) {
                        odds++;
                        if (odds >= 2) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    count++;
                    nextNode = next;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            longestPath = Math.max(count, longestPath);
        }

        return longestPath;
    }
```

This program worked only for these 2 test cases when I tried this during an exam last month , but it failed others which I was not aware of and got a score of 16 out of 100.

I am trying hard to figure out what is the correct approach and the issue in my code.

Can you please help me what is the issue in this code and how to solve this. Also I want to print the actual longest path like `0->2->3->8` for example 1 and `0->6->4` for example 2.

Comment: Instead of us debugging your algorithm to solve the problem for you. Maybe try to debug it yourself. Also maybe try different approach if this one does not work? See if some modification of breath-first or Depth-first search could simplify your algorithm.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think your problem is currently at the `int next = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);`. It seems you're only using the largest next node of the sorted `arrayList`, instead of checking all of them as valid paths. I would try to rewrite it your code as a recursive approach, so you can go back and try a different node as soon as you've reached the end OR encountered a second odd value, so you can verify all possible paths.

Comment: Shouldn't the solution to example 2 be 0->6->4 ?

Comment: @SaiBot,yes correct, I updated it now

Comment: @SDJ Apparently not, since the OP of that question and this question are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer with depth-first search.

Initially, you have to transform your input array into an adjacency-list, which will be used in the depth-first search later on. You can do it like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> tree = new ArrayList<>();

int longestPath(int[] T) {
  int n = T.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tree.add(new ArrayList<>());
  }
  //we do this to denote that there is an edge between u and T[u] and vice-versa
  for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
    if (u != T[u]) {
      tree.get(u).add(T[u]);
      tree.get(T[u]).add(u);
    }
  }

  return recurse(0, -1, false);
}
```

On each step, you need to know which node are you currently at (call it `node`), which was the node from which you jumped to the current node (call it `parent`) and a flag that tells whether or not you have already visited an `odd` valued node (the `boolean seeOdd` parameter).

The answer to the problem is the level of the deepest node you can reach, given the constraints.

Here is the recursive depth-first search code:

```
int recurse(int node, int parent, boolean seenOdd) {
  //if we enter an odd numbered node and we have already 
  //visited another odd-valued one, then we cannot proceed and just return 0
  if (seenOdd && node % 2 == 1) return 0;

  //find out how deep can we go, given the restriction
  //we can visit at most one odd-valued node
  int max = 0;
  for (int next : tree.get(node)) if (next != parent) {
    max = Math.max(max, recurse(next, node, seenOdd | (node % 2 == 1));
  }

  //we add 1 to the answer, because we should 
  //also count the node we are currently at
  return 1 + max;
}
```

As we start from node `0`, which doesn't have a parent node (i.e. we can use `-1` to show that), we call `recurse(0, -1, false);`.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I need to use this code? Input for my program is an array, so not able to co-relate how can I uses this.

Comment: I tested with my example inputs `{ 0, 9, 0, 2, 6, 8, 0, 8, 3, 0 }` and `{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0 }` I got output as 5 & 4 with your answer instead of 4 & 3.

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks. Not it should be fine.